# Is JavaFX fully open-source?

Tags: license, java

It's unclear to me whether all components that comprise JavaFX are open-source. Statements on this that I found around the web seem to be unclear too.

The [official OpenJFX website](https://openjfx.io/) seems to imply that it is fully open-source, but doesn't go into detail.

However, the [JavaFX Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX#License) states:

> Parts of the core JavaFX runtime are still proprietary software and its code has not yet been released to the public, however developers and executives behind the technology are moving toward a full opening of the code.

This statement is based on two deeply outdated links and it's unclear which parts were proprietary at the time.

Are all components of JavaFX open-source now or not? And if not, which ones aren't and are those non-essential?

Comment: According to the debian copyright file, openJFX is GPL2+CE with some permissively licensed dependencies. It does exclude two files (I believe due to unclear licensing). Not sure if it is the same as the oracle JFX.